# Is the empty set a member of any collection of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

empty set is an subset of any sets maybe any collection of sets.

I wonder what about the case of the empty set being a member,not subset, of any collection (family) of sets.

Comment: No, there is no reason why it should be an element.

Comment: The empty set is an element of every power set.

Answer (score 3):

This not true in general. For example, the empty set is a collection of sets that does not contain the empty set (because it does not contain any members).

Comment: Nice seeing familiar names.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: the only element of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is $\{\emptyset\}\ne\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

$\varnothing\in\mathcal{P}(\varnothing)$ but $\varnothing\notin \varnothing$.